Ltac matches applications of constructors of a type
I want to write a tactic that applies a tactic to every hypothesis that is at least a one-level deep application of constructors. For example, apply the tactic to 0 = m and S n = m, but not n = m.
Is there way to match this in Ltac without enumerating all the possible constructors?

Your example is not consistent with your natural language explanation.  Do you want your higher-order tactic to apply only to hypotheses that are instance of equality?  And then the left-hand side should be an application of a constructor?

It is just an example. I want the tactic to apply to things where I can specify that there should be an application of a constructor. In the case of the example, this should preferable work both for the equality or just for 0 and S n.

But 'S n' is a natural number, so it is not a type, so it cannot be an hypothesis...

Good point, I guess as in the example "S n" is not itself the hypothesis, but part of the hypothesis.

There is the is_constructor tactic.  https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.19.0/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.is_constructor
Here is an example of usage:
Ltac apply_if_eq_with_construct_on_left :=
  match goal with
  |  id : ?x = _ |- _ =>
      is_constructor x; idtac id
  | id : ?x _ = _ |- _ =>
      is_constructor x; idtac id
  | id : ?x _ _ = _ |- _ =>
      is_constructor x; idtac id
  | id : ?x _ _ _ = _ |- _ =>
      is_constructor x; idtac id
  end.

Lemma example x y : S x = y -> True.
Proof.
intros H.
apply_if_eq_with_construct_on_left.

When executing, you see that the tactic idtac is called on hypothesis H.  There are a few limitations here: it only recognized constructors applied to up to 4 arguments, and it only works on one hypothesis.  If you want to collect all the hypothesis that have the required shape, consider using revert to remove each recognized hypothesis from the goal context, and repeat to restart the hypothesis search after each detection.

This is interesting, but only if there a lot of constructors with the same amount of arguments. It doesn't really suit my needs, but is interesting nonetheless.

Whether there are many constructors with the same number of arguments was not part of the initial question.

That is what I am saying. Even though this is interesting, it is not entirely what I was looking for, because every number of arguments has to be handled seperately and I don't see how to specify a tactic that only looks for constructors of a certain data type (like nat in the example).
